# C-DEL to delete word backwards in emacs on console

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm using emacs in the Linux console.

I would like to be able to use `C-DEL`(that is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>) to `backwards-kill-word` to have an interface that is consistent with the emacs gui - as well as most other interfaces on various platform.

`C-DEL` doesn't work to `backwards-kill-word` because the sequence for complicated reasons is interpreted as `C-h` as explained in [this section of the emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackspaceKey).

How can I get `C-DEL` to delete a word back and maintain the default behaviour (help menu) for `C-h`?

Comment: I use `M-DEL` since starting using CLI Emacs. Also, save your small finger =w=

Comment: Normally I use `M-DEL``as well but I just became aware that `C-DEL` works everywhere in Windows, macOS, most GTK interfaces and emacs gui so I would like that to work in emams CLI alongside `M-DEL` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemingly, this can't be fixed by way of configuring emacs but using `showkey`, `loadkeys` and `dumpkeys` to load a custom keymap where <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> is bound to `Meta_Delete` (just like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> is by default) did the trick.